# How to write $(this) by CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, this

My CoffeeScript code:

```
a = (argu='.a') =>
    $(argu).on 'click', () =>
        $(this)
```

Compile to the Javascript:

```
var a,
    _this = this;

a = function(argu) {
    if (argu == null) {
        argu = '.a';
    }
    return $(argu).on('click', function() {
        return $(_this);
    });
};
```

I hope that `this` is $(argu) or $('.a') not _this.

How to write 'this' could refer $(argu)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inner [fat arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) (`=>`) is the reason you end up with `_this` in the click handler. If you use the normal arrow instead, you'll get what you want:

```
a = (argu='.a') =>
    $(argu).on 'click', -> # you can also remove the empty ()s
        $(this)
```

which compiles to

```
var a,
  _this = this;

a = function(argu) {
  if (argu == null) {
    argu = '.a';
  }
  return $(argu).on('click', function() {
    return $(this);
  });
};
```

This is because

> the fat arrow `=>` can be used to both define a function, and to bind it to the current value of this, right on the spot.

whereas the "skinny" arrow defines a function but does not bind it to a specific context.

---

Now, if you *really* want `this` in the callback to be `$(argu)` – note that this becomes non-idiomatic jQuery since `this` in the callback *won't* refer to the clicked element – you can do the following:

```
a = (argu='.a') =>
    $argu = $(argu)
    $argu.on 'click', (-> $(this)).bind($argu)
```

To be clear: **I do not recommend doing that.**